# How to perform "sudo su - root" without using perl modules in perl script

Tags: perl, unix, sudo

I am logged on my server using "x" user. On the CLI i can use the command "sudo su - root" and execute subsiquent commands using root user on my server. But i am not able to run this sudo su - root command in a perl script. If possible, i need the solution without using any perl module.

Comment: What about `sudo bash`?

Answer (score 0):

if you wan to execute some unix commands under root environment using your own password(user x's password) then Can you try something like this?Unix command inside **tilt**(`)

```
`sudo su - root`
```

example:

```
   use warnings;
use strict;

print "Before   :";

print `whoami`;

print `sudo su - root <<EOF

whoami


exit

EOF`;
```

above script will work you with in **root environment**.Let me know if any clarification or issues!.